# ListPlot of lists with specified x coordinate

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to do:

```
ListPlot[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...}]
```

each y being not a number but a list of numbers.
I tried:

```
ListPlot[{{x1, {y1}}, {x2, {y2}}, ...}]
```

but it does not work.

Does anybody now how to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you show a small, concrete example ?

Comment: Yes, here the example:

Comment: ListPlot[{{5, {1.`, 2.`, 3.`}}, {6.5, {7.`, 14.`, 21.`}}, {10, {50.`, 
    100.`, 150.`}}}]

Comment: Could you mean something like this?

    `listA={{5,1},{6.5,7},{10,50}};
    listB={{5,2},{6.5,14},{10,100}};
    listC={{5,3},{6.5,21},{10,150}};`
    
    `ListPlot[{listA,listB,listC}]`

Comment: That would work, but the thing is that the y lists are huge arrays of values. But I will try figure out how to convert my big y arrays into what you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going with @Sosi 's interpretation :

```
data = {{5, {1., 2., 3.}}, {6.5, {7., 14., 21.}}, {10, {50., 100., 150.`}}};
ListLogPlot[Transpose[Thread[#]  & /@ data], 
  PlotRange -> {All, Automatic}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Comment: Infinite thanks! @b.gatessucks's solution works perfect for me(with out the Log).

Answer (score 2):

```
{y1, y2, y3} = Table[i x, {i, 3}, {x, 0, 10}];
yourList = {{1, y1}, {2, y2}, {3, y3}};

toPlot = yourList /. {x_, l_List} :> ({x, #} & /@ l);
ListPlot[Transpose@toPlot, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]